# Why can't I kill the shell using the PID obtained from the $$ special variable?

Tags: shell, command-line, kill

After I have learned that the `$$` special variable holds the process number of the shell, I tried too kill the shell by simply: `kill <pid obtained by echo $$>`, however this did not work, I also tried some variations, but them also had no effect.
[image]

Comment: xargs is totally overkill here. Just use `kill $$` (although it won't work, as explained in link above). And you should copy paste the text instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: I wanted to copy paste first, but once I tried , I got a total unformatted character mess.

Comment: As with every one of your other questions, this one exhibits no effort to search: either for previous questions or how to format text on the site. Please stop being such a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but the shell tries hard not to die unless it's absolutely sure that's what is required.

SIGHUP works (as does SIGKILL), and you can try this -

```
kill -HUP $$
```

(If you prefer numeric signal identifiers the `HUP` can be replaced with `1`.)

The reason that `SIGHUP` works is that this is the signal that would have been sent when a serial line connection over a modem was terminated - for instance if the phone line was hung up.

Answer (score 3):

Check the bash manual:

> When  bash is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores SIGTERM

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Signals

Check the `kill` help text (`help kill` at a bash prompt):

> If neither SIGSPEC nor SIGNUM is present, then
>       SIGTERM is assumed.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-kill